# What arguments should I pass to invoke that method C#

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

I wanted to invoke Spectrum method at the end of the BufferReady method but I don't know why I get error which tells me that I pass wrong arguments to it. `Raw` is an `int`.

```
  void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                if (buffer.Length <= 0) return;

                // Retrieve audio data
                microphone.GetData(buffer);

                double[] sampleBuffer = new  double[(Utilities.NextPowerOfTwo((uint)buffer.Length))];
                int index = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i += 2) {
                    sampleBuffer[index] = Convert.ToDouble(BitConverter.ToInt16((byte[])buffer, i)); index++;
                }
        //ERROR UNDER
                double[] spectrum = FourierTransform.Spectrum(sampleBuffer, Raw);// I GOT ERROR HERE
            }

    -----------------------

        public static double[] Spectrum(ref double[] x, int method = Raw)
                {
                    //uint pow2Samples = FFT.NextPowerOfTwo((uint)x.Length);
                    double[] xre = new double[x.Length];
                    double[] xim = new double[x.Length];

                    Compute((uint)x.Length, x, null, xre, xim, false);

                    double[] decibel = new double[xre.Length / 2];

                    for (int i = 0; i < decibel.Length; i++)
                        decibel[i] = (method == Decibel) ? 10.0 * Math.Log10((float)(Math.Sqrt((xre[i] * xre[i]) + (xim[i] * xim[i])))) : (float)(Math.Sqrt((xre[i] * xre[i]) + (xim[i] * xim[i])));
                    return decibel;
                }
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword to first parameter of `Spectrum` method call

```
double[] spectrum = FourierTransform.Spectrum(ref sampleBuffer, Raw);
```

*UPDATE* `ref` keyword states, that array should be passed by reference to Spectrum method, and if you will assign new value to `x` in Spectrum method, then this will assign new value to `sampleBuffer` variable in microphone_BufferReady method. But as Jon stated in comments, in this particular case `ref` could be removed from your Spectrum method definition (but also you will have to modify all other calls of that method).

Comment: Not sure why it's looking for a `ref` at all -- might be better just to remove it from `Spectrum()`.

Comment: Well, this is a original signature of method he is trying to invoke, thus I think it's better than modifying method (who knows - maybe there are other places where method used)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Even if it is used elsewhere, if the method (based on it's definition) doesn't need to pass the value by reference it's probably better to remove that and fix it everywhere else it's used, as long as it's not in a widely distributed public API of some sort.

Comment: @Servy, Jon agree that in this particular case `ref` does not affect anything (because new value is not assigned to array reference) and it could be removed. It's a good notice